# IgniteUI + AngularJS "On Row Select" event

Tags: angularjs, ignite-ui

I'm sorry, I *have* Googled, looked through the Infragistics website and it's GitHub section, but I surrender.

How do you implement an "**On row select**" event, when using the `IgniteUI` library with `AngularJS` ?

Even the [IgniteUI-AngularJS GitHub](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular) page, which contains a demo, doesn't show how to do this.

Here's the jQuery method of doing it  (from [this webpage](http://www.igniteui.com/grid/grid-api-events))

```
$("#grid").on("iggridselectionactiverowchanged", function (evt, ui) {
     var message = "iggridselectionactiverowchanged";
     apiViewer.log(message);
});
```

...but I want to know how to capture this event from my AngularJS controller (and keeping the amount of jQuery to a minimum).

Is it possible ?

I also tried the standard way of adding a `ng-model` attribute to this control, and trying to put a `watch` on this variable, but even `ng-model` seems to be ignored by this control.

Has anyone used this control, successfully, using AngularJS ?

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to provide some background info about Ignite UI. Ignite UI is built on top of jQuery and jQuery UI. The Angular directives for Ignite UI provide developers with a way to declaratively initialize controls and with out-of-the-box support for two-way databinding. Still the product is not native to Angular and thus not everything that it exposes as functionality can be consumed as you would with native Angular components. That doesn't mean that you lose functionality, just some of it has to be utilized through jQuery.

To answer the specific question, you can bind event handlers declaratively [as described in the documentation](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular#handling-events).